# Plugin exposing member `QWidget` result in pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, plugins, qt5

I'm trying to develop a plugin which exposes a `QWidget` (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623813/declare-a-plugin-class-that-inherits-from-qwidget)), it's interface has something like:

```
virtual QWidget *panel() = 0;
```

While in the implementation I tried:

```
QWidget *BPlugin::panel() {
    return &m_widget;
}
```

This gives an error, app crashes on close:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9db24c3f78: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Instead, allocating `QWidget` with `new` works fine. But using `new` these days isn't that popular anymore. Should I use `new` anyway when dealing with plugins?

Comment: I assume the `widget` function in the second snippet should actually be called `panel`? It sounds like whoever is calling `BPlugin::panel` assumes ownership of the pointer they're receiving and attempts to `delete` it. If that's the case, you should return a pointer to an object you've `new`ed.

Comment: Just corrected the second snippet. Since the widget returned by `panel()` gets added in a layout, I think that's the point where ownership change happens (layouts always take ownership of things added to them, right? ). Isn't anyway around using `new`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `new` in this case? That you think it's not *popular*? You need to follow the conventions of the framework you're using. From what little I know of Qt, I think it's common for UI widgets to be `new`ed and for parent widgets to delete the children they own upon destruction.

Comment: If the returned panel has a parent set upon it, then it will be deleted when the parent is deleted, giving you the reported error.

Comment: If you want more details, you should share the code of the `BPlugin` definition and constructor, your line of code that generated the error and tell us if your plugin is still loaded when the app crashes.